# Bucle for se rompe en recursión

Tags: javascript

[EDIT]cambie el codigo de abajo por propositos de pureba.[/EDIT]
Hace un tiempo, hice un buscaminas en Java, y se me ocurrió pasarlo a HTML/JavaScript. Mi problema es que tengo una función que se comporta de una forma que no entiendo, supongo que es un problema de recursividad, ya que cuando quito la parte recursiva no tengo el problema.

Lo que pasa, el `for` recorre sólo hasta cuando ejecuta por primera vez la recursión, mientras que si quito la parte de recursión, corre entero.

Código con recursión:

```js
function revealSurroundings(i, e) {
  var bombs = 0;

  if (bombs == 0) {
    var dirx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    var diry = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];
    for (c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
      console.log("[" + i + "," + e + "]" + "-->" + c);
      var x = i + dirx[c];
      var y = e + diry[c];
      if (estaDentro(x, y)) {
        revealSurroundings(x, y);
      }     
    }
    console.log("[" + i + "," + e + "]");
  }

}

revealSurroundings(0,0);
```

Esto se ejecuta hasta que encuentra una dirección en la que ir, y "choca con una bomba en una dirección posible", (`estaDentro(x, y)` es un booleano para que no se salga de la matriz). Si aprecian los `console.log()`, muestra de valor de c `{0,1,2,3,4}`, si toco en algún casillero de la izquierda, porque la dirección 4 es la primera dirección posible, por lo que ignora la estructura `for`, que va de `c = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`. En cambio si no está la parte de recursión, sí muestra `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`.

Omití varias partes del código porque ya estoy seguro que el próblema radica aquí adentro, de todas maneras, lo pongo entero acá:

```js
var size = 9;
var matrizGlobal;
var dificultad = 1;

function resetLogic(newSize, newMatriz, newDiff){
  size = newSize;
  matrizGlobal = newMatriz;
  dificultad = newDiff;
}

function calcularMatriz(){
  var matriz = [size];
  for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    matriz[i] = [size];
    for (e = 0; e<size; e++) {
      var diff = Math.random() * dificultad;
      if(diff <= 1){
        matriz[i][e] = Math.random() < 0.83;
      } else if(diff <= 2){
        matriz[i][e] = Math.random() < 0.62;
      } else if(diff <= 3){
        matriz[i][e] = Math.random() < 0.41;
      } else {
        matriz[i][e] = Math.random() < 0.2;
      }
      //matriz[i][e] = true;
    }
  }
  return matriz;
}

function matGlobal(){
  var matrizGlobal = [size];
  for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
    matrizGlobal[i] = [size];
    for(e = 0; e<size; e++){
      //[mined, flaged, revealed, btn];
      matrizGlobal[i][e] = [4];
    }
  }
  return matrizGlobal;
}

function logicLeftClick(i, e){
  open(i, e);
}

function logicRightClick(i, e){
}

function estaDentro(i, e) {
  return !((i < 0) || (i > size - 1)) && !((e < 0) || (e > size - 1));
}

function bombArround(i, e) {
  var ret = 0;
  var dirx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
  var diry = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];
  for (c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
    if (estaDentro(i + dirx[c], e + diry[c])) {
      if (matrizGlobal[i + dirx[c]][e + diry[c]][0]) {
        ret++;
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

function revealSurroundings(i, e) {
  var bombs = bombArround(i, e);
  matrizGlobal[i][e][3].src = "image/Bomb" + bombs + ".png";
  matrizGlobal[i][e][3].disabled = true; //Button disabled
  matrizGlobal[i][e][2] = true;  //Revealed
  matrizGlobal[i][e][1] = false; //Flagged
  if (bombs == 0) {
    var dirx = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    var diry = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];
    for (c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
      console.log("[" + i + "," + e + "]" + "-->" + c);
      var x = i + dirx[c];
      var y = e + diry[c];
      if (estaDentro(x, y)) {
        if (!matrizGlobal[x][y][2]) {
          revealSurroundings(x, y);
        }
      }     
    }
    console.log("[" + i + "," + e + "]");
  }

}

function open(x, y) {
  if (!matrizGlobal[x][y][3].disabled) {
    matrizGlobal[x][y][3].disabled = true;
    if (!matrizGlobal[x][y][0]) {
      revealSurroundings(x, y);
    } else {
      mineTriggered(x, y);
    }
  }
}

function mineTriggered( x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (c = 0; c < size; c++) {
      matrizGlobal[i][c][3].disabled = true;
    }
  }
  matrizGlobal[x][y][3].src = "image/Bomb.png";
}

function reiniciarMatriz(){
            var matriz = calcularMatriz(dificultad, size);
            for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
                for(e = 0; e<size; e++){
                    matrizGlobal[i][e][0] = !matriz[i][e];
                    matrizGlobal[i][e][1] = false;
                    matrizGlobal[i][e][2] = false;
                    matrizGlobal[i][e][3] = document.createElement("input"); //IGNORAR
                }
            }
        }
matrizGlobal =  reiniciarMatriz();
open(0,0);
```

Esto es lo que me muestra, (c de 0 a 4, de 0 a 4, de 0 a 4 y se cierra)

```js
[0,0]-->0
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->1
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->2
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->3
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->4
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->0
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->1
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->2
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->3
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->4
logic.js:79 [0,2]-->0
logic.js:79 [0,2]-->1
logic.js:79 [0,2]-->2
logic.js:79 [0,2]-->3
logic.js:79 [0,2]-->4
logic.js:88 [0,2]
logic.js:88 [0,1]
logic.js:88 [0,0]
```

Yo esperaria algo asi: (c 0 a x, empieza la recursion ... se cierra c de x a 7 y muestra las coordenadas de la casilla al final)

```js
    [0,0]-->0
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->1
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->2
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->3
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->4
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->5
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->6
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->0
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->1
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->2
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->3
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->4
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->5
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->6
logic.js:79 [0,1]-->7
logic.js:88 [0,1]
logic.js:79 [0,0]-->7
logic.js:88 [0,0]
```

Cualquier ayuda o recomendación es bienvenida, siempre y cuando no incluya jQuery.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado y el que le ocurre? Corro el código y no obtengo ningún síntoma similar al que usted menciona, es más, me ocurre una recursión infinita.

Comment: esta medio cortado el codigo, tiene partes html, partes css, mas partes js, creo que para correrlo, asi a secas, hacer previamente size = 9, dificultad = 1, matrizGlobal = matGlobal(); y despues open(x, y); con algun x e y adentro de la matriz, de 0 a 8.

Comment: el esperado, es que muestre todos los valores de c, para cada combinacion de x y que llama revealSurrondings, el obtenido, es muestra los valores de c hasta que encuentra que esta dentro de la matriz, y se llama a si misma con la direccion nueva, "saliendose del for", que es lo que siento que esta pasando, porque muestra el console.log del final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** El problema está en que la variable `c` es global. Declarala como local a la función con `var c;`.

---

(respuesta original)

1. Llamamos a `revealSurrondings(0,0)`

   2. La función ve que la casilla a su derecha `estáAdentro`...
   3. ...entonces llama a `revealSurrondings(1,0)`

      4. La función ve que la casilla a su izquierda `estáAdentro`...
      5. ...entonces llama a `revealSurrondings(0,0)`

         6. La función ve que la casilla a su derecha `estáAdentro`...
         7. ...entonces llama a `revealSurrondings(1,0)`

            8. La función ve que la casilla a su izquierda `estáAdentro`...

etcétera. Ahí es donde se queda tu función. Tenés que marcar las casillas mostradas de alguna manera y saltearlas (`estaAdentro(x,y) && !estaRevelada(x,y)` o algo así).

Comment: Esta parte del codigo hace eso: if (!matrizGlobal[x][y][2]) {revealSurroundings(x, y); }  , cuando entra a un lugar que ya habia estado, no se ejecuta; el problema yace cuando se llama a si misma, no muestra todos los valores de c, que es lo que deberia pasar, porque es un for con esa condicion de c = 0, a c < 8, si quito la parte de recursion, muestra todos los valores de c.

Comment: Si pasara eso, saldria un "stackoverflow" xD, porque se llama indefinidamente, y aparece en la consola el error

Comment: Mejor es poner el código real, en vez de tratar de hacer un resumen que puede despistar, como en este caso. Descartado eso, entonces la respuesta es sencilla. Modifico la respuesta...

Comment: Te agradezco infinitamente, nunca me hubiera dado cuenta de eso, es eso, efectivamente, ahora funciona :')